# Is $\cot(z)-\frac1z$ bounded on a given circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am getting stuck with the problem given from the book Schaum's outlines p.240 Q.110

Given $f(z)=\cot(z)-\frac1z$ where $z$ lies on a circle of radius $R=(N+\frac12)\pi$ and centered at the origin. Prove that $|f(z)|\le M$ where $M$ is independent of $N$.

Comment: No source, no motivation, no indication of any work done, no indication of what you know about the problem, how far you got with it, where you got stuck, and so on. Very tempting to vote to close the problem.

Comment: OK, you've given a source. That's a good start. Don't the Schaum books always have solutions?

Comment: no, since it is a supplementary problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $z\mapsto{1\over z}$ is bounded by $1$ for $|z|\geq 1$; therefore we don't have to bother about this part of $f$.

Writing $z=x+iy$ we have
$$|\cot z|^2=1+{\cos(2x)\over\sin^2 x+\sinh^2 y}\ .\tag{1}$$
Now let $R:=\bigl(N+{1\over2}\bigr)\pi$ for some $N\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, and let $\gamma_R$ be the circle of radius $R$ around the origin. Note that $\sin R=\pm 1$. When $z \in\gamma_R$ and $|x|\geq R-{\pi\over4}$ then $\sin^2 x\geq{1\over2}$, and it follows from $(1)$ that $|\cot z|^2\leq 3$. On the other hand, when $z \in\gamma_R$ and $|x|\leq R-{\pi\over4}$ then
$$\sinh^2 y\geq y^2=R^2-x^2\geq {R\pi\over 2}-{\pi^2\over 16}\geq{3\pi^2\over16}>1\ .$$
From $(1)$ we now conclude that $|\cot z|^2\leq 2$ in this case.

Altogether we can say that $M:=3$ is an admissible bound for $|f|$ on the circles $\gamma_R$.

Comment: Christian, this is fine, so +1.   But note that for $|x|\ge R-\pi /4$, $\cos(2x)\le 0$.  Therefore, $|\cot(z)|^2\le 1$ when $|x|\ge R-\pi /4$.  And for $|x|\le R-\pi/4$, $
|\cot(z)|^2\le 1+\frac{16}{3\pi^2}<1.6$.  So, a tighter bound is $1.6$.

Comment: @MarkViola For $|x|\leq R-\pi/4$, $|y|\geq\sqrt{3}\pi/4$, then $|\cot z|\leq |\coth\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{4}|\approx 1.140935<1.15$.

Comment: @HGF What is your point please?

Comment: @MarkViola I have learned a lot after reading you and Christian Blatter'answers. I have no other intention, just want to say that using $|\cot z|\leq \coth|y|$, maybe we can get a better estimate.